# Error conversión .CSV a .XML

Tags: php, xml, csv

He creado un Script con la siguiente función, para recoger la información que tengo en un archivo productos.csv y convertirlo en un .xml para importar posteriormente en mi tienda.

```
function createXML(){
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

    $inputFilename    = 'import/productos.csv';
    $outputFilename   = 'import/productos.xml';

// Open csv to read
    $inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
    $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
    $doc  = new DomDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
    $root = $doc->createElement('rows');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
    while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $container = $doc->createElement('row');
        foreach($headers as $i => $header)
        {
            $child = $doc->createElement($header);
            $child = $container->appendChild($child);
            $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
            $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }

        $root->appendChild($container);
    }

    $strxml = $doc->saveXML();
    $handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $strxml);
    fclose($handle);
    echo ('ejecutado');
}
```

Al ejecutar me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Invalid Character Error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php:45 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php(45):
>   DOMDocument->createElement('ID;ACTIVO;TIPO;...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php(66):
>   createXML() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php on line 45

Parece ser que tengo algún error en el foreach que se encarga de apuntar los datos recogidos en el .xml, pero no consigo ver cual es el problema.
Como apunte, decir que si borro el contenido de dentro del foreach, me crea los "row" en el .xml pero sin nada dentro.

Añado la primera línea del .csv:

> ID;ACTIVO;TIPO;CATEGORIA;PRECIO;TIPOIVA;ALAVENTA;IMPORTEDESC;TANTDESC;FINICIODESC;FFINALDESC;CODART;REFPROV;PROVEEDOR;EAN13;ALTO;ANCHO;PROFUNDIDAD;PESO;STOCK;MULTIPLOCOMPRA;UNIMINIMA;NOMIDIOMA1;NOMIDIOMA2;DESCIDIOMA1;DESCIDIOMA2;DESCLARGAIDIOMA1;DESCLARGAIDIOMA2;METATITULOCAS;METATITULOCAT;METADESCCAS;METADESCCAT;IMAGENES;PERSONALIZABLE;VISIBLE;PLAZOENTREGA;CARACTERISTICAS;CARACTERISTICAT;BORRARIMAGEN;PDF;WEB;MANUFACTURER

Comment: Tiene pinta de haber un caracter que no se consigue leer, Invalid Character Error in C:\xampp\htdoc.... y quiza lo reciba CreateElement(), funcion que está dentro de tu foreach  Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php(45): DOMDocument->createElement('ID;ACTIVO;TIPO;...'). Revisa que datos recibe y si no puede manejarlos

Comment: Vale, parece ser que ese es el problema, pero no entiendo por que no puede leer los carácteres... Incluso he borrado todo el contenido del .csv y al ser un csv delimitado por comas, me da el mismo error pero del siguiente modo:  DOMDocument->createElement(';;;;;;;;;;;;;;...')

Comment: `ID;ACTIVO;TIPO` etc, supongo que son nombres de columna. ¿Alguna de ellas empieza por número, caracteres especiales, espacio, etc? XML tiene sus limitaciones en ese sentido, [ver aquí](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html) para más detalles.

Comment: No... es lo raro, de hecho, he probado solo poniendo 3 campos: nombre, correo y id para para asegurarme que no quedan caracteres raros... pero sigue haciendo lo mismo...

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar y pegar del CSV la línea completa de los nombres de columna: `ID;ACTIVO;TIPO .... .... ...` ? Incluso las palabras con espacio dan error.

Comment: He editado la pregunta y lo he añadido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publico respuesta:

Al parecer "fgetcsv" tiene predefinido un tipo de separador, que en este caso es la ",".
Al tener un CSV, delimitado por ";" no me lo detectaba y me marcaba las "," del texto como salto.

He definido el delimitador de la siguiente manera, en las dos lineas que lo uso:

```
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile, '0', ';');

while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, '0', ';')) !== FALSE)
```

Una vez cambiado esto, funciona todo perfecto.